# Android ExpandableListView with 2 sub levels

Tags: android

How can i achieve ExpandableListView with 2 sub levels ? Can anyone help me out ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked this blog ,this may help you...

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.in/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

Add one [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) where you add the subviews

Comment: what i had is expandableListview with single child item..What i want is, when i click one of the child item the next level of child should appear..I think this i can't achieve with your answer..

Comment: I misunderstood the question, check this out http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

Comment: this one only i tried..This one actually use only one sub level child item .I need two.